# Forcing single-thread access to a resource

Tags: c#, thread-safety, dispatcher

Currently I have multiple resources in a project that can only be accessed from a single thread. One example is a ZeroMQ server and another is a Mitsubishi PLC communication module that's not threadsafe.

Right now I create a seperate thread for any resource requiring single-threaded access. I haven't wrapped this in a class or anything, so I have a `ThreadStart` (void) method and a couple of properties in every class requiring coordinated access to a resource. I then use a dispatcher combined with `Invoke` / `BeginInvoke` to force access from the seperate Thread only.

**Is there some class already available that can coordinate access to a resource from a single thread?**

Here's some sample code that will get me a Dispatcher right now:

```
object theLock = new object();
Dispatcher dispatcher = null;

lock (theLock)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        lock (theLock)
        {
            dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            Monitor.Pulse(theLock);
        }
        Dispatcher.Run();
    })).Start();

    Monitor.Wait(theLock);
}

dispatcher.Invoke(...);
```

I can wrap this code in a class just to create a thread and dispatcher whenever I need one, but I can't imagine this being the best solution to coordinate access to a thread-unsafe resource.

Comment: It's in **bold**, should I've put the question near the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)? You could enqueue in there tasks that need to access the resource, and start a task that dequeue and run the task, one after each others so there is no race condition?

```
static BlockingCollection<Action<StringBuilder>> queue = new BlockingCollection<Action<StringBuilder>>();

//Your thread unsafe resource...
static StringBuilder resource = new StringBuilder();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var action = queue.Take();
            action(resource);
        }
    });

    //Now to do some work you simply add something to the queue...
    queue.Add((sb) => sb.Append("Hello"));
    queue.Add((sb) => sb.Append(" World"));

    queue.Add((sb) => Console.WriteLine("Content: {0}", sb.ToString()));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It's all static and a bit ugly and certainly needs rework, but it should be ok. The idea is that you enqueue lambdas that you want to execute, and they will be executed one after each other so you don't have to synchronize on the resource.

Comment: Will that force them (the `Task`s) to be executed on the same thread, always? Will it decrease complexity? A short example would say more than a thousand words here...

Comment: Ok I didn't get the question right then... You want to make sure it's always the same thread that is executing everything? In this case it will, I suppose, as there is only one task running.

Comment: But then how would I process the queue, and what would force the queue processing to stay in the same thread? Seems to me I'd still need to create a separate thread to do this and then instead of a `Dispatcher` I would have some sort of queue. Also, what if the queue runs out? Do I need a monitor there? I'm missing the queue processing part, but I think it still misses the issue of coordinating access to a resource through a single thread.

Comment: It's a blocking queue, so when there isn't anything in there, the processing is suspended until there is something. As soon as there is something in there, the Action is executed and given the resource as a parameter, so only that Action access the resource at that time.

Comment: Ok, that clears up a lot. But still, that would give me a `BlockingCollection` instead of the `Dispatcher` and the threading part will be the same. However now I also use `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)` which won't be possible with a `BlockingCollection`, so I can't see any advantage of using that yet.

Comment: Two years later and I see you're right! There is one issue with your code though, and that's the long-running thread with a `Task` construct. It's easy to queue some container with a `TaskCompletionSource` to implement the async pattern using `Task`s and then process it in the consumer thread.